# Ethstat / Interface Grafana CollectD not showing correct value (MB/s)

Tags: interface, graphite, grafana, collectd

I use Grafana with CollectD (and Graphite) to monitor my network usage on my server.
I use the 'Interface' Plugin of CollectD and display the graphs like this:

```
alias(scale(nonNegativeDerivative(collectd.graph_host.interface-eth0.if_octets.rx), 0.00000095367431640625), 'download')
```

When I now initiate a downlad with a speedlimit. The download runs for approx 10 minutes, but only [image] this is shown (green line is the download). So it only shows a peak.

Do I have to use some other metrics? I also tried the 'ethstat' but that has so many options none of which I understand!

Is there any beginners documentation. I only found the CollectD Docs, which I read but that does not say anything what the metrics of the ethstat actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any beginner documentation about the ethstats metrics meaning in collectd. This is because the ethstat plugin reports statistics collected by ethtool on your system and the ethtool stats are vendor specific.

To point you in the right direction, run `ethtool -S eth0`

That should show you names and numbers like what collectd is reporting.

Now run `ethtool -i eth0` and find your driver info.

Then, google your driver name and find out what statistics your card reports and what they mean. It may involve reading linux driver source code, but don't be too scared of that. What you want is probably in the comments, not the code.